# ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel not working with Repeater and RadioButtons

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a repeater which includes a radio button in each item, and the whole thing sites inside an update panel.  When I select a radio button the whole page reloads.  Why is it not just updating the update panel.  I've reduced this to a pretty simple example to avoid clutter.  Code here...

ASPX...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="history">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="radioButton" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="HistoryGroup" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckChanged" /><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <p><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="output" /></p>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code...

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                list.Add(i);
            history.DataSource = list.ToArray();
            history.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void RadioButton_CheckChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        output.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing "UpdateMode="Conditional" and test it.

Comment: That didn't work for me, the whoel page still reloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to remove the GroupName from the RadioButton.  When I remove this tag it fires asynchronously and just updates the panel.  I don't actually need this tag anyway (due to the known bug where GroupName doesn't work on RadioButtons in Repeaters) as I handle the grouping within my click event (i.e. uncheck any other RadioButtons of the same name in other repeater items).

Answer (score 3):

Setting ClientIDMode=Auto on the RadioButton should fix it (it's an infamous .NET bug, http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/584991/clientidmode-static-in-updatepanel-fails-to-do-async-postback)

Answer (score 0):

please add up1.Update() after output.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(). Your  RadioButton is not the trigger for updatepanel