# AJAX In ItemTemplate Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In this aspx code example the Timer inside UpdatePanel in ListView doesn't make async refresh. In this code it refreshes the whole page like AJAX doesn't exists here. What should I do to remove this problem ?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="SIMPLE FIELD"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:ListView ID="DataListView" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="500"></asp:Timer>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="AJAX"></asp:Label>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Move your `UpdatePanel` outside `Listview Itemtemplate`

Comment: Check out the following link,it worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13753848/2233219

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the entire ListView in the UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="DataListView" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>            
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="500"></asp:Timer>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="AJAX"></asp:Label>                
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an issue where because the ListView doesn't do any rendering of its own, the UpdatePanel can't figure out the "parent" item to update. I think it's an unfortunate consequence of the design of the UpdatePanel.

I would recommend trying to put the UpdatePanel inside its own container control, such as an  and see if that produces the correct result.